# Print JSON Data in the Input, angular

Tags: angular

I am trying to print data from a json delivered by console, the data delivered to the console print it on the input

this is the component ts

```
    examenClicked = (exa) => {
    this.dataService.getOneExamen(exa.id).subscribe(
      data => {
        this.selectedExamen = data;
        console.log('JSON DATA --->', data); 
      },

error => {
    console.log(error);
  }
);
}
```

this is the component html

```
<button class="btn btn-primary"  (click)="examenClicked(examenes)">Detalle</button>     
              nombre examen <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="selectedExamen.nombreExa"><br>
              detalle examen <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="selectedExamen.descripcionExa"><br>
              creacion del registro <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="selectedExamen.release_date"><br>
              fecha del examen<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="selectedExamen.fechaExa"><br>
              categoria examen<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="selectedExamen.categoriaExa"><br>
```

[that data print in the text box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fozmG.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your console.log() we can see that you are using **old** Http, please update to using `HttpClient`. `Http` has been deprecated for ages! You can refer to the documentation: [`HttpClient`](https://angular.io/guide/http)

But in short.... So remove `HttpModule` and `Http` and replace those with `HttpClientModule` and `HttpClient`.

In app module:

```ts
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

// ....

imports: [
  //...
  HttpClientModule
]
```

create an interface (or class), since you should type your data:

```ts
// name interface how you want
export interface Examene {
  id: number;
  nombreExa: string;
  // rest of properties here!
}
```

In your service:

```ts
import { catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

// ....

constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { }

getOneExamen(id): Observable<Examene> {
  return this.httpClient.get<Examene>('....').pipe(
    catchError(...)
  )
}
```

and then component:

```ts
selectedExamen = <Examene>{};

examenClicked(exa) {
  this.dataService.getOneExamen(exa.id).subscribe(
    (data: Examene) => {
      // with httpClient we don't need to parse json, so this works with HttpClient!
      this.selectedExamen = data; 
      console.log('JSON DATA --->', data); 
    },
    error => {
      console.log(error);
    }
  );
}
```

### BUT

If you are using a reaaaaally old version of angular and have to use `Http` for some reason, you are missing `data.json()` from your code, that's why it doesn't work as expect. Before `HttpClient` we needed to parse the json from response, but HttpClient does that for us now. So in that case your code should look like:

```ts
this.selectedExamen = data.json();
```

Comment: i'm using angular 5 and import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http'; thnx por the answer :D

Answer (score 0):

Data is not appearing because you have object as value.Passing value like this will solve problem `this.selectedExamen = data._body`

```
 examenClicked = (exa) => {
   this.dataService.getOneExamen(exa.id).subscribe(
     data => {
      this.selectedExamen = data._body;
      console.log('JSON DATA --->', data); 
     },

     error => {
      console.log(error);
    }
    );
   }
```

Comment: maybe the problem is this? in the service  `getOneExamen(id): Observable<any> {
  return this.http.get(this.baseurl + '/examen/' + id ,
  {headers: this.headers});
   }`

Comment: `getExamenes(): Promise<Examen[]> {
  return this.http.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/examen?format=json', { headers: this.headers })
   .toPromise()
   .then(response => response.json() as Examen[])
 }`

Comment: What is response returning?,if only returning body then will work.On subscribe in question response data object contained res,header.. but you only needed body response,to access data was needed to be like example : `data._body.nombreExa`

Answer (score 0):

```
     examenClicked = (exa) => {
    this.dataService.getOneExamen(exa.id).subscribe(
      data => {
        this.selectedExamen.nombreExa = data.nombreExa;
        this.selectedExamen.descripcionExa= data.descripcionExa;
        this.selectedExamen.release_date= data.release_date;
        this.selectedExamen.fechaExa= data.fechaExa;
        this.selectedExamen.categoriaExa= data.categoriaExa;
        console.log('JSON DATA --->', this.selectedExamen); 
      },

error => {
    console.log(error);
  }
);
}
```